# Exclude Google results containing search term in title?

Tags: google-search

I'm searching Google and wish to limit results to ones that contain my search term in the page body but **NOT** the page title. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `-intitle:[Your Search Term]` at the end, in the Google search box.

Answer (score 7):

[documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html)

`allintext: Google search`

you can combine this with `allintitle: -Google search`

Comment: Oops, it looks like this solution doesn't exclude the search term from the page titles. Page titles still appear that contain the search string.

Comment: Invariably there are going to be bodies about a subject where the title contains the same string as the body. This searches bodies only, so you won't end up with any pages that have a Title with the string and no content of the string in the body. What you want to do is find pages where a string is in the body and not mentioned in the title? I thought you just wanted to ensure the string was in the body..

Comment: I want pages where the string is in the body but not the title. Is there something like "notintitle"?

Comment: `allinbody: "orange" AND allintitle: -"apple"`

Comment: hmm, adding `allintitle: -"term"` to the end of my query doesn't work the way it does in yours.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @Raystafarian's answer (which I also could not replicate), I found this solution:

```
body: gabe AND body: tycho AND title: -gabe AND title: -tycho
```

You have to specify the terms separately, but this appears to work just fine.

Comment: This gets me closer! Now, is there a way to limit these results to a single domain?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, "body" and "title" are just highlighted in the search results

Comment: You can limit searching to a single domain by adding `site:example.com` to your search string.